# How to include static HTML into Concrete5

Tags: html, redirect, concrete5

I have successfully installed C5 into my hosting which is in "http://www.myweb.com.my" (not a real page or url of mine, just for example), note that my C5 web domain is on .com.my.

Eventhough the domain is .com.my, C5 that I installed used the base url of "http://www.myweb.com" which is also in my hosting and all the C5 directory is in there.

I've created a static HTML page that is not built using C5, and I would like to include this static HTML page into C5 url which is "http://www.myweb.com.my/content/static.html" how do I do that?

I keep getting "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found" when i try to use "http://www.myweb.com.my/content/static.html" which i already uploaded into my hosting which is in the base url as in "http://www.myweb.com/content/static.html"

What do I have to configure to make my C5 web to recognize the static HTML and display it in "http://www.myweb.com.my/content/static.html" instead of "http://www.myweb.com/content/static.html"?

Or is it possible to create single pages in C5 and redirect it to my base url to view "http://www.myweb.com/content/static.html" without changing the current C5 url in browser?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is this just an HTML file that exists inside the `content` directory of your public web directory on the server? If so, then I think the problem is that you don't have your .htaccess file set up properly. Specifically, make sure you have these two lines in your .htaccess file above the "RewriteRule" line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

These lines tell Apache that if an actual file exists at the requested location, serve them as-is instead of using the RewriteRule that follows.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple page in single_pages directory. All content inside (static or PHP generated) will be encapsuled into the view.php of your theme. Then go to admin and add your page created.